# HBase (Easy): How to Perform Range Prefix Scan in hbase shell

Tags: hbase, database-scan, hbase-shell

I am designing an app to run on hbase and want to interactively explore the contents of my cluster.  I am in the hbase shell and I want to perform a scan of all keys starting with the chars "abc".  Such keys might inlcude "abc4", "abc92", "abc20014" etc...  I tried a scan

```
hbase(main):003:0> scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => 'abc', ENDROW => 'abc'}
```

But this does not seem to return anything since there is technically no rowkey "abc" only rowkeys starting with "abc"

What I want is something like

```
hbase(main):003:0> scan 'mytable', {STARTSROWPREFIX => 'abc', ENDROWPREFIX => 'abc'}
```

I hear HBase can do this quickly and is one of its main selling points.  How do I do this in the hbase shell?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

So it turns out to be very easy.  The scan ranges are not inclusive, the logic is start <= key < end.  So the answer is

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => 'abc', ENDROW => 'abd'}
```

Comment: That's right - looks like you found this out the hard way. :) Do you want to mark this as the right answer?

Comment: however hbase doc should say that startrow is actually startrowprefix

Comment: If your rows only use 'ASCII' values then it is as simple as you describe here. If you really use binary rowkeys then it becomes a lot more difficult. Check here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11990 to see what discussion and edge cases trying to create a generic solution brought to light.

Comment: Does this {STARTROW => 'abc', ENDROW => 'abd'} have a Java API equivalent? I've only managed to find PrefixFilter and this range-like approach would suit me better

Answer (score 44):

In recent versions of HBase you can now do in the hbase shell:

```
scan 'mytable', {ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'abc'}
```

This effectively does this (and also works for binary situations)

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => 'abc', ENDROW => 'abd'}
```

This method is a LOT more efficient than the "PrefixFilter" approach because the latter puts all records through the comparison code the is present in this PrefixFilter class.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the PrefixFilter, when startrow and stoprow appear to be superior. Do you know of any usecases? I've also heard that people combine all three.

Comment: I never use the PrefixFilter at all anymore. Perhaps there is a good reason to use it when doing something in a coprocessor, otherwise I would even vote to remove the class from HBase altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been using it this whole time because I mistakenly assumed that you needed to have an exact match on the start and end rows. I ran a test on 5million rows divided between 26 different rowkey prefixes, and the prefix filter is about 300% slower for me on average. Now I'm spending my Saturday refactoring all of my jobs :)

Comment: Not sure if you would know the answer to this, but I figured I would send it your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197883/how-does-the-use-of-startrow-and-stoprow-not-result-in-a-full-table-scan-in-hbas

Answer (score 26):

The accepted solution won't work in all cases (binary keys). In addition, using a PrefixFilter can be slow because it performs a table scan until it reaches the prefix. A more performant solution is to use a STARTROW and a FILTER like so:

```
 scan 'my_table', {STARTROW => 'abc', FILTER => "PrefixFilter('abc')"}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the `PrefixFilter`, when `startrow` and `stoprow` appear to be superior. Do you know of any usecases? I've also heard that people combine all three.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.  My key is composed of AAA_B_CCC.  I needed all the rows where the key started with AAA_.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a filter

checkout the answer for following question
[Scan with filter using HBase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256100/how-to-scan-hbase-from-hbase-shell-using-filter)

more filters are listed in http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.filter.html

Comment: I am under the impression filters are much slower that range scans.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942638/should-i-user-prefixfilter-or-rowkey-range-scan-in-hbase.  Is there a way to do do this with a range scan?

Comment: @DavidWilliams : Yes, range queries are faster.