# Google Cloud Bigtable: query partial keys

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

So if I have the following data in Bigtable:

```
DEL_6878 .....
DEL_6879 .....
BOM_5876 .....
SFO_8686 .....
SFO_8687 .....
```

How do I query for say SFO* records? I read the documentation; I know how to get single row; something similar to this:

```
table.get("SFO_8686");
```

Or how to get a range; something like `getRows("SFO_8686", "SFO _8687")` which takes in `startKey` and `endKey`, but I read in the documentation and was made to believe that one can get records that start with prefix; the SFO* example. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I would think that running a Scan with a range is your most efficient option.  You can also use a scan with `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter` with a `RegexStringComparator`.

Comment: The documentation specifically says I can query with SFO* kind of operations. IF the key is made up of multiple data points, AND at query time I only know the value of part of the key, the SFO part, then how do I even formulate start and end?

Comment: Just for my own clarity, which documentation are you referring to?

Comment: Oh.. you mean "SFO_" is an obvious start, but it's unclear what the end key should be?

Maybe

    byte[] bytes = "SFO_".getBytes();
    bytes[bytes.length-1] =  (byte) (bytes[bytes.length-1] + 1);


I'm not sure off hand.

Comment: Let's take specific example from documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series

In the document example for smart meters, read this section: "Taking the queries together, the row key will need to be of the form DATE + METER     ...... 

To query all meters for a given day, retrieve a range of rows using DATE" 

So how does one keep a key of DATE+METER, and then query for all rows for a day, like 01July2016, across meters. Query like 01Jul2016*? If in the documentation one can have a query example on how to go about it, then that's the thing I am after.

Comment: Your easiest solution is likely to be a scan with a PrefixFilter.

I'll make a note to beef up our examples for the time series use cases.

Comment: Wouldn't scan do full table scan? Can't I do startKey = SFOa, endKey=SFOz? Assuming that the key parts after SFO are alphabets, wouldn't that mimic SFO*? The documentation does state the rows are stored in lexicographic order.

Comment: You can definitely do a scan with a start and end key.  I don't know off hand about whether or not it does a full table scan.

Comment: The documentation has left anything more than trivial to "figure it out". Fit case to be put on SO documentation

Comment: Add to that scant community on SO, AND Google claim in the help documents that the BigTable questions are actively answered on SO - I am not getting good vibes on using the system.

Comment: I sent your feedback to the team.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, PrefixFilter works well for partial row-key *-style scans and from what I managed to dig out, setting the start and end rows in addition to that should improve performance (presumably by avoiding the full scan):

```
PrefixFilter px = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
s.setFilter(px);
...
```

Also, from what I understand from this discussion:
[HBase (Easy): How to Perform Range Prefix Scan in hbase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558547/hbase-easy-how-to-perform-range-prefix-scan-in-hbase-shell)
, is in the shell environment, the 'ROWPREFIXFILTER' is meant to combine the two elements above:

```
scan 'TableName', {ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'SFO'}
```

But I have not managed to find a java-equivalent of that, if that's what you are after. Would be helpful to hear if others have!