# When to use PrefixFilter?

Tags: hbase

I hit slow query problem with `PrefixFilter`

After looking at

[Should I use prefixfilter or rowkey range scan in HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942638/should-i-use-prefixfilter-or-rowkey-range-scan-in-hbase)

and

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/55204/recommended-way-to-do-hbase-prefix-scan-through-hb.html

I see that `PrefixFilter` is doing full table scan, then I would want to ask, since `startRowKey` and `stopRowKey` works fast, what's the point for HBase to provide the `PrefixFilter` API, I think this filter API should not exist at all, or when could I use `PrefixFilter`?

Comment: using this (Java) code I did not observe any performance issue and I'm quite sure that no full scan is peformed
     `scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(rowPrefix));`
     `scan.setRowPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(rowPrefix));`

Comment: Yes，the code you provides has no performance issue, then what about `scan.setPrefixFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(rowPrefix)))`?